# Changing operation flow in nodejs

Tags: node.js, oop

I am trying to create an ecommerce website in nodejs.
I want it to be modular so that we can add extensions later without editing the main codebase. For example suppose I have an extension which checks if a user is requester or approver, and if he is an approver he can checkout, otherwise a approval request will be sent to corresponding approver.
Suppose I emit an event when a checkout is made, then that extension can catch it and process it. But at the same time I want the normal flow to be changed. How can I do that?
 Should I create a checkout module extending original checkout module and override functions and make sure that extension's module is loaded ? If I do it there will be problem if two different extensions are adding features to same core module.
What is the best way to do it ?

Comment: In what context are u talking ? webapp or REST services ?

Comment: Right now its webapp only.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, there are two ways widely used to extend a web app :

1. [Webhooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking)
2. [Api](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)

Both have their pros and cons.

What you are trying to do is possible in hook style, because the code will be execute on the server itself and you can extend some objects and modify their behavior as you want.